# AngularJS view not updating when $scope.$apply is called

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Here's the workflow:

A user's account page should list all of the object owned by that user.

Next to each object is a "delete" button that opens a Bootstrap modal. The modal asks the user if they truly want to delete the object, and if they confirm, then the modal should dismiss, the object should be deleted, and the view should update to reflect the deletion.

I am dismissing the modal using the `data-dismiss` attribute on the confirmation button inside of the modal.

Here is the function in my controller that deletes the object and (should) update the view:

```
 $scope.deleteObject = function(object) {
    object.destroy({
      success: function(object) {
        $scope.$apply();
      }, 
      error: function(object, error) {
        // handle error
      }
    });
  };
```

However, I have to refresh the page to see the updated view with the object removed.

Is there another way I should be using `$scope.$apply`?

EDIT: I found a workaround by creating a new $scope level function to load my collection of objects. Previously, this was done when the controller is loaded (not attached to any particular function.

In other words, my old code did this:

```
.controller('AccountCtrl', function($scope) {
  var query = new Query('Object');
  query.find().then(function(objects) {
    $scope.objects = objects;
  });

  $scope.deleteObject = function(object) {
    object.destroy({
      success: function(object) {
        // do something
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Now I've wrapped the `find` code in a $scope level function, which I can call explicitly when an object is destroyed:

```
.controller('AccountCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.getObjects = function() {
    var query = new Query('Object');
    query.find().then(function(objects) {
      $scope.objects = objects;
    });
  }

  $scope.getObjects(); // call when the view loads

  $scope.deleteObject = function(object) {
    object.destroy({
      success: function(object) {
        $scope.getObjects(); // call again when an object is deleted
      }
    });
  }
});
```

I'm still hoping there is a cleaner solution to this, i.e. one where I don't have to manually update by object collection.

Comment: This may help http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html

Comment: what about using $timeout callback and calling $apply in it

Comment: This should work without $apply - you have problem somewhere in code

Comment: @Sn0opr `$timeout` will automatically call `$apply` internally.... is effectively another way to trigger a digest all by itself

Comment: where is `destroy` code....does it remove object from array that is in controller scope?

Comment: The destroy code is from the Parse.com Javascript SDK.

Answer (score 0):

In your success you have to modify the local $scope.objects.

In you last exemple you should try this (code not tested, but this is how it should look):

```
$scope.deleteObject = function(object) {
    object.destroy({
      success: function(object) {
        var objectIndex = $scope.objects.indexOf(object);
        $scope.objects.splice(objectIndex,1);
      }
    });
  }
```

In your controller you take the responsibility for updating your model. Angular take the responsibility for updating the view. Calling again the $scope.getObjects() is a way to do it. But the cleaner way is to implements your update of the model in case of success. You should also give an error method in case the server response is an error.

If you have correctly bind the collection to your view, i should update after a delete. Tell me if it helped you out.